# How can I get list of symbols, abbreviations, abstract, acknowledgements into Table of Contents before Introduction, and under roman numerals?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have managed to make a decent Table of Contents. However, it does not include the following items:

1. List of Abbreviations
2. List of Symbols
3. Abstract
4. Acknowledgements

My Table of Contents has no problem listing the item from Introduction onwards (set in arabic numerals) but the items highlighted above (and set in roman numerals) do not appear. Basically, I want List of Abbreviations, Symbols, Abstract and Acknowledgement to appear BEFORE Introduction, and under roman numerals. Thank you so much.

[image]

I have posted my code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{fullpage}


\usepackage{siunitx} 


\usepackage{siunitx} 


\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=1.25in, bottom = 1.25in]{geometry} 


\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}


\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{booktabs} 


\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{rotating} 


\usepackage{placeins} 


\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption} 


\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{12}{12} 


\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents 


\pagebreak


\listoffigures 


\pagebreak


\listoftables %Includes List of Tables%


\pagebreak


\section*{List of Abbreviations}


\pagebreak


\section*{List of Symbols}


\pagebreak


\section*{Abstract}


\pagebreak


\section*{Acknowledgment}



\pagebreak


\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Off topic: don't add blank lines in LaTeX unless you know what it is doing. Blank lines can make the code a bit more readable, but it will cause you troubles some days. For example, you can't compile your code if there is a blank line in `equation`. Also, don't load a package more than once.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I am afraid it has nothing to do with character recognition. :(

Comment: @UvuvuvwevweUgwemubwemOssas Ops, I clicked on the wrong link, I'll retract my vote.